# Angular2-Incorporating single page functionality to MVC C# application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, angular

Is there a way to convert an Angular 2 C# MVC application to have single page functionality or is that somewhat unrealistic?

The web application that I am working on is rather large and contains roughly 15 different components.  The routing is all set up at this point.  Is single page worth looking into or does the size or the sight put it out of scope?  If so, how would I go about beginning to incorporate this feature into my project? I am not asking for a step-by-step tutorial rather to just be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular 2 is a single page (SPA) framework.  So if you are using Angular 2 with MVC then you already have some SPA functionality.  Maybe your MVC is serving up pages and each page has a different instance of an Angular 2 app.  If this is the case and you would like to consolidate to just a singular Angular 2 instance, then you would need to either convert the MVC app into a Web API or add API endpoints for Angular to consume.
Unfortunately, I can't speak to whether or not this is worth it for your project.  I would recommend doing some research on the benefits of a single page app to see if they align with your goals.